# Ruby on Rails exporting data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I got a rails site and a mysql db. 
I need to perform archiving one of my models.
What are my options? does rails got some built in capabilities? does mysql got any?

Comment: Can you expand a little on what you mean by archiving.  Do you mean removing old records from the active table and storing them somewhere else where you can get to them with the code, or just backing them up and deleting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rake db:dump will dump your schema and the contents of your database.
rake db:load will load the contents of the dump back into your db

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to use the [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) export utility.

Answer (score 2):

To backup:

```
 mysqldump -u user -p DATABASE > backup.sql
```

To import:

```
 mysql -u user -p DATABASE < backup.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need some easy database backup, I would suggest to take a look on either mysqdump or mysqlhotcopy (see also the [MySQL Backup methods).](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html)
You can combine this with a [cronjob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) which runs frequently and executes the backup task.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using ActiveRecord associations and building a simple callback function that could export your data to some other format (pdf, csv, html, or whatever wild example). Listen for a success from the callback function and then call your .destroy() or .delete() or whatever garbage method you choose on SomeObject.

look into Association_callbacks here: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

options aside, mysqldump is pretty darn efficient!